# React-big-calendar rendering problem in WEEK and WORK_WEEK views

Tags: reactjs, debugging, rendering, render, react-big-calendar

I'm using react-big-calendar with these properties:

```
<Calendar
            culture="fi"
            events={data}
            titleAccessor={titleAccessor}
            localizer={localizer}
            startAccessor="startTime"
            endAccessor="endTime"
            style={{ height: 580 }}
            messages={defaultMessagesFi}
            views={["day", "work_week", "week", "month", "agenda"]}
            onView={onView}
            view={view}
            onSelectEvent={handleEditDialogOpen}
            onSelectSlot={handleNewDialogOpen}
            scrollToTime={dayjs()
              .set("hour", 8)
              .set("minute", 0)
              .set("second", 0)}
            formats={formats}
            eventPropGetter={eventPropGetter}
            selectable
            dayLayoutAlgorithm="no-overlap"
          />
```

When I open the calendar page, header looks like this at the begninning:
[image: wrong]

and after 200-300ms it looks normal:
[image: normal]

What could cause this and how could I fix this issue? Or is this even issue? I have tried to delete some of the properties but it has not helped. This problem is only in WORK and WORK_WEEK views. In Month and Day views everything working as expected.